# The inverse of maskoceans in basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

Long story short: I am determining how big percentage of an area of either open ocean or a fjord that is covered by lat/long points. To determine the area that is covered by lat/long points I am planning on computing minimum bounding geometry or using a cell based approach. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154202/how-to-quantify-the-coverage-area

However, to know how much of space that is covered in %, I need to know how large the water area/fjord is in total. I see that basemap has a maskoceans function (http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.maskoceans) that I recon gives all the land area from an area. However, is it an opposite maskland function, or any other function to get only the water area in python?

Any other suggestions to get only water area in python is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this in matplotlib.basemap:

is_land(xpt, ypt)

Returns True if the given x,y point (in projection coordinates) is over land, False otherwise. The definition of land is based upon the GSHHS coastline polygons associated with the class instance. Points over lakes inside land regions are not counted as land points.

Comment: I just want to highlight an important distinction:

>Returns True if the given x,y point __(in projection coordinates)__

Remember to do the following:

`lat,long = map(lat,long)`

Thank you!